# Tmux: Prompt to select window for join-pane while still seeing window numbers and titles?

Tags: tmux

I routinely join panes in tmux, and would like to create a binding that would prompt me for the window to join, while still letting me see the window numbers and titles.  My first approach was based one of the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/266567/tmux-how-can-i-link-a-window-as-split-window):

```
bind-key < command-prompt -p "create pane from #(tmux list-windows|awk -vORS='  ' '/^[0-9]/{print $1 $2}'):"  "join-pane -s ':%%'"
```

But tmux does not do the interpolation it does with other commands such as "display-message", and the prompt itself is taking up the status line so I cannot see the window numbers and titles.

My second approach was to attempt to leverage choose-window, which displays an interactive list of windows:

bind < choose-window "join-pane -hs %%"

This mostly works, but it takes up the entire current window while I'm choosing.  I would like to do something like bufexplore does in vim where the window is split first, then a prompt appears in the new pane where I select the window to pull into it.  The following seems pretty close to what I want, but I'm left with the pane that was used to display the prompt sitting around:

```
bind < split-window -h \; choose-window 'join-pane -hs %%'
```

I'd move the window instead, but, as far as I can tell, you can't move a window to a pane (or move a pane at all without joining), and the following does not work:

```
bind < split-window -h ; choose-window 'move-window -s %%'
```

I suspect that the approach involves something like the following sequence of operations:

1. Split window
2. Choose-window (pane)
3. join-pane
4. kill previous pane (the one that held the choose-window prompt)

But, when I try to do something like the following:

```
split-window -h ; choose-window 'join-pane -hs %%' ; kill-pane -t.-1
```

The Pane killed is the one I started from, NOT the one used to display the prompt.  Indeed, changing the value for kill-pane, or issuing a select-pane first does not seem to make a difference.

Perhaps this cannot be done, perhaps there is a way to move a window/0-pane to a new pane, but I can't figure it out.  Perhaps there is some combination of interactive commands and calls to

```
run "tmux <command> etc etc %%"
```

That will fix it, but I can't figure it out.  Ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/238702/maximizing-a-pane-in-tmux) may help. It shows a nice way of "zooming" a pane into a full window, then restoring it to its original position, via a temporary window. It's sort of the reverse of what you are attempting, but you may be able to adapt some ideas.

Comment: If I reverse that method (i.e. join-pane and then break-pane) by trying something like this:

`split-window -h ; choose-window 'join-pane -hs %%' ; break-pane -t.-1`

It immediately pushes the current window up by one, and creates a new window behind the current one that contains the full-screen choose-window prompt.  Upon selecting, it works identically to the first method I discussed above.

Comment: This was an awesome question, I had never even thought to try and add prompting for commands that didn't already have it.  I added two new bindings into my tmux as a result, one for horizontal and one for vertical.  Thank you for asking this and thank you @chris-johnsen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could kill the initial, temporary pane before `join-pane` re-splits the window:

```
bind < split-window -h \; choose-window 'kill-pane ; join-pane -hs %%'
```

Comment: AHA! That does it!  That's the magic sauce of command ordering I was looking for.  Well done!

Comment: Just to finalize, I also have:

`bind > break-pane -d`

Which I execute in any split to send it back where it came from (without leaving the current window)